# Is INSERT RETURNING guaranteed to return things in the "right" order?

Tags: postgresql, insert, sql-returning

Example:

```
create table foo(
    id serial, 
    txt text
);

insert into foo(txt) values ('a'),('b'),('c') returning id;
```

Returns:

```
 id 
----
  1
  2
  3
(3 rows)
```

It *seems* that the *first* `id` in the return value will always be the `id` for `'a'`, the second for `'b'` and so on, but is this defined behaviour of `insert into`, or is it a coincidence that may fail under odd circumstances?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I don't see anything in [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html) that guarantees an order for `RETURNING` so I don't think you can depend on it. Odds are that the `RETURNING` order will match the `VALUES` order but I don't see any guarantees about what order the `VALUES` will be inserted in either; the `VALUES` are almost certainly going to be insert in order from left to right but again, there is no documented guarantee.

Also, the relational model is set based so ordering is something applied by the user rather than an inherent property of a relation. In general, if there is no way to explicitly specify an ordering, there is no implied ordering.

Execute summary: the ordering you're seeing is probably what will always happen but it is not guaranteed so don't depend on it.

Comment: I'm aware that relations are unordered, but I wasn't sure whether the `values` part is to be modelled as a relation or a list :) I hoped it might be a special case, since the (order-independent) alternative `insert into foo(txt) values ('a'),('b'),('c') returning (txt,id)` seems mildly wasteful (guess I'm prematurely optimizing again...)

Comment: @FunctorSalad: The `values` probably are treated as a list but I don't see it guaranteed anywhere. And if dealing with the order from `returning` is your performance bottle neck then you're probably doing okay :)

Comment: Agreed, *absolutely* do not rely on it. PostgreSQL is well within its rights to sort the inputs however would result in best insert performance, and if index-organized tables are ever implemented, it probably will.

Comment: @Craig: I think the difference between *specified/guaranteed behavior* and *incidental/empirically-verified behavior* is one of those nasty lessons that people have to learn the hard way; I got lucky and learned early on by working with ten difference C compilers and Unixen at once. That's why I'm always down on the "try it and see what it does" approach to software, "try it, see what it does, then justify that behavior from the specs" is better but I prefer to start with the specs and assume nothing that isn't there.

Answer (score 31):

While the documentation isn't entirely clear, it does state that:

> If the INSERT command contains a RETURNING clause, the result will be similar to that of a SELECT statement containing the columns and values defined in the RETURNING list, computed over the row(s) inserted by the command.

Now "similar to" isn't an ironclad guarantee, and I've [raised this for discussion on the mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/pgsql-hackers@postgresql.org/msg253739.html) ... but in practice, PostgreSQL won't mess with the order of values in `RETURNING`. It's unlikely we'll ever be able to even if we want to for optimisation, because too many apps rely on it being ordered the same as the input.

So... for `INSERT INTO ... VALUES (...), (...), ... RETURNING ...` and for `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... ORDER BY ... RETURNING ...` it should be safe to assume that the result relation is the in the same order as the input.

Answer (score 7):

While this won't help you *now*, 9.1 will include ["writeable common table expressions"](http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2011/03/16/waiting-for-9-1-writable-cte/).  That's the official name for the [`WITH` syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html).  ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_table_expressions).)

This new ability should let you place your `INSERT ... RETURNING` inside a `WITH`, give an alias, and then `SELECT` against that with a specific ordering with a plain old `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: This is interesting, but only tangentially related.  It could be used as a close approximation of what the OP is asking *only if* the INPUT order can be expressed with an unambiguous and equivalent `ORDER BY` as well.

Answer (score 4):

I have benchmarked this with a few thousand rows, over and over again.

**It does NOT return the values in order.**

[image]

So the best way I found out to guarantee the right order is to create a temporary table and a temporary column in the destination table with the index from the array of the values that shall be inserted and then match them back by PrimaryKey and Index of array before loading it into your return function.

Comment: 1298 in the first row`0: 1298` is the id, in OP's SQL ?  and which version of postgres you tested ?

Comment: it is the ID in my tests, i tested for thousands of rows. Tested on 12.2 and 11.5

Comment: @HendrikThurauEnterprises could you provide the example you created? I created a temp table, populated with 10k rows, and the order from `returning` matches my `values` list. Maybe 10k isn't enough rows?

Answer (score -2):

**Disclaimer**: Answer refers to **MariaDB 10.5+**

As with PostgreSQL, the order of `RETURNING` is not documented in detail, so I ran a primitive test case where the returned result sets were definitely sequential and in sync with the value tuples of the bulk insert:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `returning_order_test_on_dup` (
    `ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `VAL` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`), 
    UNIQUE INDEX `VAL` (`VAL`)
);
```

The following queries generate the bulk insert queries used to populate the test table. Both queries generate 25k insert values each, with the second one being offset by a few thousands to make sure that `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` does work properly:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT('INSERT INTO returning_order_test_on_dup (VAL) VALUES ', GROUP_CONCAT('(', seq, ')'), ' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE VAL = VALUES(VAL) RETURNING *;')
FROM seq_1_to_25000;

SELECT CONCAT('INSERT INTO returning_order_test_on_dup (VAL) VALUES ', GROUP_CONCAT('(', seq, ')'), ' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE VAL = VALUES(VAL) RETURNING *;')
FROM seq_20000_to_45000;
```

**Note**: `seq_*_to_*` is a builtin sequence generator

To be "safe", I looked at the tests of the `INSERT ... RETURNING` implementation ([PR #1384](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/pull/1384)) and glanced over the implementation, and couldn't find a hint anywhere that value tuples and the `RETURNING` rows are exoected to be able to diverge.

- [mysql-test/main/insert_returning.test](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/10.5/mysql-test/main/insert_returning.test)
- [mysql-test/main/insert_returning.result](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/10.5/mysql-test/main/insert_returning.result)

Tested with `MariaDB 10.6`