# INSERT multiple values in one query (order)

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here's my query:

```
INSET INTO cities (name, country_id)
VALUES ('New York', 11), ('London', 215), ('Moscow', 66)
```

Is it right to say that rows will be inserted excactly in order of query? So, New Yor will be inserted first, than London, than Moscow. Is it possible that London will be inserted first? 
I can't find this information in postgresql documentation.

edit:

So, I need to know is it safe to think that first id will be for New York, second for London, third for Moscow.

edit2:

I just need to associate city with returned id.
Full query:

```
INSET INTO cities (name, country_id)
    VALUES ('New York', 11), ('London', 215), ('Moscow', 66) 
    RETURNING id
```

So, it's not possible for multiple insertion?

edit3:

My question duplicates this one: [Is INSERT RETURNING guaranteed to return things in the "right" order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439293/is-insert-returning-guaranteed-to-return-things-in-the-right-order)
So, I guess to make sure I need to make each insert in it's own query.
Thanks.

Comment: Why is it important for you?

Comment: I'm using "RETURNING id" at the end of the query. So, I need to know is it safe to think that first id will be for New York, second for London, third for Moscow.

Comment: I don't think you can rely on the ids being returned in the same order, but I can't find a reference in the manual for that.

Comment: don't guess based on order, return the data that allows you to know you are correct. I've answered below.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Exactly - there's nothing that says you *can*, so you can't. Right now, it'll generally work, but PostgreSQL is free to change that in a future optimisation to support, e.g. index-organized tables. Even if you used a `SELECT ... FROM (VALUES (...)) ORDER BY ...`, Pg would not be obliged to insert the rows in that order. SQL's all about sets, not "tables", something people tend to forget (not least because the spec its self can't make up its mind).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to return multiple values, so you could match them up that way, for example:

```
INSET INTO cities (name, country_id)
    VALUES ('New York', 11), ('London', 215), ('Moscow', 66) 
    RETURNING id, name, country_id
```

just pick the columns you want to return.

Comment: What if names and country_ids could be identical? Cities is just an example.

Comment: You'll have to give more detail in your question, I think I answered what you where asking? .. on the face of it, I'd say you had a design problem, but I don't know anything about what your doing. Perhaps you could use a time stamp on insert then order by that in your selects.

Comment: @user1561346 In SQL you shouldn't generally be inserting identical rows. (Doesn't mean it doesn't happen, just shouldn't generally be doing it). This approach, returning multiple values, is the correct one.

Comment: @Craig Ringer, why not? Can you explane? Rows are not identical, they have unique id.

Comment: @user1561346 Well, if they have a unique input ID, you can easily tell which is which, right? Your only concern here is if `country_id` isn't unique on input.

Comment: @CraigRinger, do you understand that returned IDs will be used in program further? For example for another insertion in another table for connection. What are you suggesting if I insert 100 values in each insert? Do I need to compare all values in array before insertion with all returned values after? It's really strange. BTW, I was not asking for help with SQL query, I was asking to confirm or decline my statement.

Answer (score 1):

the data are not stored in specified order.

Answer (score 0):

If there is not an "ORDER BY" clause, then the SELECT statement does not necessarally return the records in the same order as inserted.

Perhaps you should add an auto increment identity field in your table and then order results by this field.

Comment: I think you might've misunderstood the question; the user is asking whether an insert ... returning will return a list of IDs in the same order as the input values appeared in the `VALUES` clause.

Comment: Yes you are probably right, but when I posted my answer the user hadn't post his 3 edits. I am not sure till now what he means.

Comment: @CraigRinger, true. I think it's because of my poor english.

Answer (score 0):

If you are too concerned about the order of the inserted data, add a column to your table to work as a sequence, specify it during the isnert

Example:

```
INSET INTO cities (
  seq, 
  name, 
  country_id
)
VALUES ( seq + 1,  'New York', 11)

INSET INTO cities (
  seq, 
  name, 
  country_id
)
VALUES ( seq + 2,  'London', 215)... etc
```

of course initialize your sequence by getting the previous `seq` value from your already inserted data

Comment: Er, what? If you were going to do that, surely you'd use a `SERIAL` column, or a system sequence? The whole point of the question is that they're trying to match up input values in an `insert` to the returned IDs in the `returning` clause. You're not using multi-valued inserts, so the problem is moot.