# PostgreSQL: How to select and update from a table as if it were a queue

Tags: postgresql, locking, sql-update, queue

I'd like several processes to pull from a table as if it were a queue.  The requirements:

1. Order of the items is important, and must be specified in the query
2. Each process (of which there are an unknown amount) can get chunks of N items at a time
3. Each item must only be processed once
4. I don't want to lock the table (for performance reasons)

I have a working solution, but would like some other opinions.

First attempt:

```
UPDATE foo
SET should_select=0
FROM
        (SELECT
                *
        FROM foo
        WHERE
                should_select=1
        ORDER BY id ASC
        LIMIT $N FOR UPDATE) as to_select
WHERE
    foo.id = to_select.id
RETURNING to_select.*;
```

This works, but does not return the $N results in order, as "RETURNING" does not guarantee order.  I could sort on client side, but that will require loading all of the results into memory, and if $N is large this is not efficient.

Second attempt:

I can use an advisory lock so only 1 process can grab from the queue at a time, and then do two queries:

```
SELECT pg_advisory_lock( 123456 );

SELECT
        *
FROM foo
WHERE
        should_select=1
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT $N;

UPDATE foo
SET should_select=0
WHERE id IN (<list of $N ids...>);

SELECT pg_advisory_unlock( 123456 );
```

However, I'm not a fan of the IN clause.. this seems very bad for performance.

I'm using version 9.3.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked around a bit.  There is some talk about controlling the returning order here : [returning order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439293/is-insert-returning-guaranteed-to-return-things-in-the-right-order).  This was an older question (pre 9.1 maybe), but there was a reference to the CTE. That's the ticket, right? Here is my favorite page about stuff you should be using in postgres (including CTEs): [The best Postgres Features ...](http://www.craigkerstiens.com/2013/11/18/best-postgres-feature-youre-not-using/). So, using a with clause I could coerce the order of a returning * like:

```
WITH FOOUP as (
UPDATE foo
SET should_select=0
FROM
    (SELECT
            *
    FROM foo
    WHERE
            should_select=1
    ORDER BY id ASC
    LIMIT $N FOR UPDATE) as to_select
WHERE
    foo.id = to_select.id
RETURNING to_select.*)
select * from FOOUP order by id asc;
```

That looks like it should be super efficient, and you should get the tuples back in the correct order.  Maybe you could leave off the FOR UPDATE?

-g

Answer (score 3):

```
DELETE FROM queue
WHERE itemid = (
  SELECT itemid
  FROM queue
  ORDER BY itemid
  FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
  LIMIT 1
)
RETURNING *;
```

Source:

1) https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/what-is-select-skip-locked-for-in-postgresql-9-5/