# paginating the data from postgresql for multiple clients with global cursor

Tags: sql, postgresql

So, i need to process parts of some huge dataset(100.000.000+ records) simultaneously by multiple instances of processing script, running on separate servers. each instance will be processing it's own chunk of data, no data will be given to more than one instance. I would give records in chunks of 50/100 to each instance. The question is - **how to organise the pagination?** I think that some sort of global pointers shout be stored on the DB side (`PostgreSQL`). `CURSOR` is not of use here because it exists within the transaction.

The dataset consists of multiple text files stored 1 line per row and will be queried though `b-index`. sample columns: `uuid`, `file_name`, `line`, `line_nr`, `date`.

The idea i have is to create a cursors table and to store the cursor current value(which will refer to `line_nr`) for each `file_name` after every request.

Is that an efficient way to do it, or there is some built-in functionality in `PostgreSQL` which would allow me to do it?

Answer (score 3):

SELECT FOR UPDATE with SKIP LOCKED. You'll want to create a work queue table with claimed_at/completed_at timestamp columns that the workers update as they complete their work. The other column of work queue table will be a reference to your dataset's table's PK (you probably won't want to use a real foreign key for performance reasons). Then you can use a modified version of this query:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49403339/16361

We'll use a larger limit in order to allocate chunks of tasks at once. And, instead of deleting, we'll set the claimed_at timestamp, and use a filter on claimed_at being null to avoid double-claiming. Your application code would be responsible for the 2nd update to set the completed_at timestamp. As a tertiary advantage, you can query your work queue table's completed_at - claimed_at timestamp to keep track of how long each task is taking, and you can query for completed_at IS NULL when everything is done to see any rows that caused workers to crash or that otherwise did not complete.

```
UPDATE work_queue_table set claimed_at=now()
WHERE dataset_row_uuid = (
  SELECT dataset_row_uuid
  FROM work_queue_table
  WHERE claimed_at IS NULL
  FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
  LIMIT 50
)
RETURNING dataset_row_uuid;
```

The setup of the work queue table could be as simple as this:

```
CREATE TABLE work_queue_table AS
SELECT uuid AS dataset_row_uuid,
    NULL::timestamp AS claimed_at,
    NULL::timestamp AS completed_at
FROM the_dataset_table
```

Though you many need to instead turn it into a regular CREATE & multiple INSERTs that you can run in parallel if this takes too long (I haven't created a huge table like this since PG gained multiprocessing features, it's possible that doesn't actually help anymore).

If it's good/helpful to have tasks from the same file handled by the same worker, you can change the ORDER BY to file_name, line_nr instead. There's a lot of tweaks you can do for various use cases, hopefully this can get you started.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of clients is constant, each could fetch its next batch with

```
SELECT ...
FROM atable
WHERE id > previous_id
AND id % number_of_clients = client_no
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 50;
```

Here `previous_id` is the maximal `id` from the previous batch, `number_of_clients` is the number of clients and `client_no` is different for each client.

That avoids taking locks if you don't need them.

Comment: thanks for response. my mistake, the description is a bit simplified - actually the instances will be running on the different servers and each instance will be processing the data in multithreaded manner, so single connection is not really an option.