# Does INSERT RETURNING guarantees order of returned rows

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sql-insert

Does `INSERT ... RETURNING` returns rows in order of the input? The documentation is unclear about that. This would be very useful to get the ids of inserted rows and use those in associated records.

In fact I think this is what the [import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) package (for Rails) does, e.g.:

```
authors = [Author.new()]
books = [Book.new(author: authors[0])]
Author.import(authors)
Books.import(books)
```

Will set the correct author_id in books for the imported books, based on the author. In the console, the sql statement seems to be an `INSERT ... RETURNING`, and then I guess the models are updated behind the scenes with the ids.

But then, is this a feature of Postgres? Or its just this package that sort this out somehow.

Similar question was raised here without any result, maybe this time somebody can confirm.

Comment: RETURNING is supported by Postgres, Oracle and SQLite. I don't think its in any of the SQL standards. SQL-server has `RETURN [integer]`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is INSERT RETURNING guaranteed to return things in the "right" order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439293/is-insert-returning-guaranteed-to-return-things-in-the-right-order)

Answer (score 2):

`INSERT ... RETURNING` will return rows in the order that they are inserted, but that is an implementation artifact. I guess that this won't change, but there are no guarantees.